# I don't understand the error in this code while verification through a pass key

Tags: javascript

So I am creating a website in which a person is asked whether he is an authorizer or a user. If he is a user, he should automatically be taken to a login screen.

If he is an authorizer then he has to enter a passcode for confirmation. (Yes the code is a bit weird, my brother set it in the app version that he is making for I don't know what reason, it's temporary.)

The user part of it works, but the authorizer part doesn't. Even if I type the correct passcode for the authorizer key, it still shows the error that I wrote in for when it was incorrect.

As per what I know about Javascript (I'm not too good at it), the code should work right. I even checked the else if's and they were connected to the if's that I wanted to connect to.

```
  const authPass = "I Love You!";

  function signUp() {
    
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var passwordconfirm = document.getElementById("password2");
    var authkey = document.getElementById("authkey");

    if (password.value == passwordconfirm.value && email.value != "") {
      if (document.getElementById("Authorizer").checked) {
        if (authkey == authPass) {
        const promise = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
        
        var initAuth = true;

        alert("Signed you up, redirecting to login page...");
      });
    } else{
        alert("Incorrect Authorizer Key.");
        return false;
        }
      }
    } else if (password.value == "") {
      alert("Please enter a password");
      return false;
    } else if (passwordconfirm.value == "") {
      alert("Please confirm your password");
      return false;
    } else if(password.value != passwordconfirm.value) {
        alert("Passwords do not match. Please try again.");
        return false;
    } else if (email.value == "") {
      alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
    }
   
    if (password.value == passwordconfirm.value && email.value != "") {
      if(document.getElementById("User").checked) {
        const promise = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // ...
        });

        var initUser = true;

        alert("Signed you up, redirecting to login page...");

      }


    } else if (password.value == "") {
      alert("Please enter a password");
      return false;
    } else if (passwordconfirm.value == "") {
      alert("Please confirm your password");
      return false;
    } else if(password.value != passwordconfirm.value) {
        alert("Passwords do not match. Please try again.");
        return false;
    } else if (email.value == "") {
      alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
    }
  }
```

Comment: The failing auth key handling else is matching the `password.value == passwordconfirm.value && email.value != ""` if and not the `authkey == authPass` The nesting is completely off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing `if (authkey == authPass) {` but `authkey` is an HTML element. You need `if (authkey.value == authPass) {`

Comment: thanks a lot! worked out and I got why it wasn't working as well. thanks again